# Check if file exists and remove it with python on share without paramiko

Tags: python, unix, share

I want to check if a certain file `fake-file.txt` exists on a shared folder `//123.456.7.890/Data/` and if it does I want to remove it and write a new file `real-file.txt`. I do **not** want to use paramiko module for this task and got it working on a windows machine like this:

```
filename = '//123.456.7.890/Data/fake-file.txt'
if os.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
    #and so on
```

However, this method does not work on a unix based machine (CentOS in this case). I get an IOError that the file doesnt exists. I am not really familiar with unix based machines so there is probably something going wrong with the reference. How can I fix this problem? If something is unclear, let me know!

PS. the folder is password protected and I am able to ssh to it from the terminal

Comment: May I question why you don't want to use paramiko ? You said that you access the file with ssh, so that definitly seems like a job for paramiko ... You can also use `subprocess` and execute raw commands ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a Python question. It's that on Linux you access remote filesystems by mounting them onto a local empty directory (which may require privileges you don't have) and then access them through that directory (then known as a mountpoint). Something like

```
$ mkdir ./1234567890
$ mount -t cifs //123.456.7.890/Data -o username=username,password=password ./1234567890
```

if this succeeds, the linux filename you use inside your Python program will be `./1234567890/fake-file.txt`.

Some Linux systems may be configured with an automounter system so that particular filestore references automagically do the mount for you. You'll need to talk to your local system management to establish whether and how this is implemented locally.

PS 123.456.7.890 is not a valid IP address but I'm assuming you chose to hide the real and valid IP address that you were actually using. 123.45.67.89 is a better choice for a "random" IP address, or 192.168.22.33 (random private IP).